Would it be possible to prove Liouville's theorem from the analyticity property of holomorphic functions alone?
Obviously a polynomial is either constant or unbounded, and from Liouville's theorem it seems to follow that the same is true for a power series with an infinite radius of convergence. (Such a function is holomorphic everywhere in $\Bbb C$, I think.)
Let's look at this the other way around.
An arbitary entire function is equal to its Maclaurin series, if I'm not mistaken. Would it be possible to use this fact alone to prove Liouville's theorem? (What I mean when I'm saying "alone" is that we should not use, at least not directly, Cauchy's integral formula or the Cauchy estimate, contrary to what is the case in the standard proofs.)
I have an idea about what such a proof would look like, but so far I'm not able to make the pieces fit together.
A power series with an infinite radius of convergence (for example a Maclaurin series of an entire function) converges uniformly on any disc (regardless of its size). So it should differ in magnitude to a partial sum, which is a polynomial, by at most 1, let's say, everywhere in a particular disc that we choose. And that polynomial is unbounded if it's not constant. However we don't know if it explodes in magnitude already in our chosen disc or only outside of it. If we have to leave the disc in order to make the polynomial explode, then that's a problem since we don't know anything about the difference in magnitude between the polynomial (the partial sum) and the power series on the outside.
Something is lacking in the argument, apparently, but maybe it’s possible to make it work somehow. Does anyone have any suggestion?

Liouville's Theorem is quite non-trivial. Its proof may not be long, but the proof uses several preliminary results, especially, Cauchy's Theorem.  The behavior of sums of  convergent power series  is very different from that of polynomials. If this  was not the case, Complex Analysis would have  been a trivial subject!

Yes, but a power series with an infinite radius of convergence seems to resemble a polynomial in so far as it's either constant or unbounded. Maybe we can show this without using Liouville's theorem or Cauchy's integral formula. If we could, then we would have the kind of proof of Liouville's theorem that I want.

One big difference between the two: A non-constant polynomial $p$ satisfies the property $|p(z)| \to \infty$ as $|z| \to \infty$. Never true for any entire function which is not a polynomial.

Interesting! That's surprising. I will think more about this later today when I have time to do that.

You need maximum modulus (which can be obtained with power series only) and then consider $g(z)=f(1/z)$ which is analytic in the punctured plane and bounded at zero hence it is analytic there (this also just power series manipulations) then if $M$ is the supremum of $f$ it is either attained in the plane so $f$ constant or it is attained by $g$ above at $0$ so $g$ is constant hence $f$is

Great suggestion, Conrad. I will think about this also.

I'm trying to remember what is normally used in the proof of the maximum modulus principle. So analyticity is enough to prove it?

Liouville's theorem for analytic [power series defined] functions in no way depends on integration theory.  This means you don't need Cauchy-Goursat or Cauchy Integral Formula, etc.  I suggest picking up a text using the Weierstrass approach to complex analysis especially Beardon's-- he indicates considering $\big \vert \frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z}\big \vert$ for $0\lt \vert z\vert \lt t$ with help of max modulus theorem then letting $t\to \infty$.

to prove maximum modulus, look at the normal form - so say the function is analytic on some domain and has a local maximum modulus at $w$ then $f(z)=f(w)+c(z-w)^ng(z)+O(|z-w|^{n+1}, n \ge 1$ near $w$ where $c \ne 0$ and $g(w)=1$; but then choosing $z=w+(f(w)\bar c)^{1/n} \epsilon$ for some root determination (and $f(w)\ne 0$ as otherwise $f=0$) you get $f(z)=f(w)(1+|c|^2\epsilon^n)+O(\epsilon^{n+1}$ so $|f(z)| >|f(w)|$ for $\epsilon>0$ small enough

I'm glad to hear this, user 8675309. That Liouville's theorem for analytic functions can be proved without using any results from integration theory is precisely what I imagined, what my intuition told me. My textbook however presents Liouville's theorem as a corollary to Cauchy's integral formula, which I didn't like somehow.

Thanks for explaining, Conrad. I will try to understand how the maximal modulus principle follows from analyticity.

Assuming the Fundamental Theoremm of Algebra, here's an outline of the weakest proof I can think of. FTA $\implies$ Argument Principle for polynomials $\implies $ polynomials are open maps $\implies $ weak max modulus theorem for analytic $f$, i.e. on $\overline B(0,r)$ $f$ has a max on the boundary by considering polynomials uniformly converging to $f$.  Now for bounded entire $f$ restricted to $\overline B(0,t)$ (mimicking Beardon) $\big \vert \frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z}\big \vert \leq \max_{ \vert w\vert =t} \vert \frac{f(w)-f(0)}{w}\vert \leq \frac{M +\vert f(0)\vert}{t} $ and send $t\to \infty$.

Ok, great, user8675309. I like weak proofs, which don't presuppose more than absolutely necessary. But I guess that if we want to prove Liouville's theorem from the fundamental theorem of algebra, then we have to assume that the latter theorem can be proved purely by algebraic means. Otherwise we probably get circularity since Liouville's theorem is precisely what is used in the standard proof of the fundamental theorem of algebra. Am I right?

@AA I suggest you do a search on this site as there are an enormous number of proofs of FTA.  The closest to "purely algebraic" that I'm aware of uses Intermediate Value Theorem [real analysis] + Algebra [Galois].  The proof I like comes down to homotopy invariance of winding numbers [e.g. Steenrod & Chinn's book or Fulton's Algebraic Topology].  Beardon's book uses a winding number argument but without notions of homotopy.  Technical nit: my prior argument  should say "$\vert f \vert$ has a max on the boundary..."
